# AutoCAD Plugin Assembly multiple Versions

Tags: .net, reflection, versioning, strongname, autocad-plugin

I developed multiple Plug-ins for Autodesk AutoCAD. In order to avoid repeating tasks I also created several libraries. Now it happens, that our customers sometimes have Plugin A with MyLibrary v1.0 and Plugin B with MyLibrary v1.1. How can I load both versions of MyLibrary into AutoCAD?

As AutoCAD itself does [not provide strong named Assemblies](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/can-i-sign-my-autocad-net-plug-in-with-a-strong-name.html), I cannot strong name MyLibrary. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Just install all .net framework runtimes you are using in your mix.
I use at the moment Framework 4.6. this works with all installed acad versions as long the framework is on that machine.(Even with earlier ones) There is no real technical need to make x different libs. There is also no real need to use the "special SDK for that acad version". I run still the sdk from 2016 even with the version 2020. As long you do not need a special API which is only in the lates SDK it will work. The .Net SDK provides also just wrapper to the C core of autocad.